# Combining Mixamo actions in Blender with different start positions

Tags: animation, rigging, mixamo

I'm trying to use Blender's NLA to combine some [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/) actions, as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NrsSdEUSWI).

I have three actions, which will be used in the following sequence:

1. Start walking
2. Continuous walking (repeat x 4)
3. Stop walking

The walking action contains the option to download "in place" or not.
The others do not come with that option.
I'm making a repeat loop of four on the continuous walk.

When I try to combine the actions using the NLA, my character jumps forwards or backwards:

https://vimeo.com/722169168/19d39529f8

I have enabled auto blend and tried adjusting the overlap between them.

What's the right way to compensate for this?

Key-framing the overall rig's position each time an action changes feels wrong. Is there a better way?

(I'd prefer not to require another plugin if possible)

Comment: I think I found the answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIP8QibQ7XU&t=129s - edit the action in the graph editor, adjust the Z axis on the hip bone until the actions that were moving forward are now moving in place.  Then do overall positon keyframing to the whole rig

Comment: There's a complete series of videos by CGDive about animation including retargeting Mixamo animations [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm4me6ZZRk8&list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJux9f5Bvb1QlByiHWTK3ICP&index=1&t=0s).