# Merging fbx animations of the same model

Tags: animation, rigging, .fbx, gltf

I have about 10 animations of an FBX model. The geometry of the model is the same but each animation is different.

I want to merge all 10 animations into a single gltf file, i.e. I want to have a single model and skeleton but retain the 10 different sets of keyframes and interpolation parameters.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266953/combining-mixamo-actions-in-blender-with-different-start-positions. <-- this may help. I found this tutorial useful for explaining how to merge animations into one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NrsSdEUSWI

Comment: Excuse the ignorance, that seems to be for mixamo animations but I have fbx files, would it still work?

Comment: I'm not sure? I think so? When I export from Mixamo, I chose FBX animations, which then import correctly into Blender (total beginner at this myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting glTF animations are briefly covered in [this section of the Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#animation).

When you have multiple different animations to store in a single glTF, they can be encoded separately using the *Nonlinear Animation* panel, as "NLA" tracks.

[image: screenshot of "push down action"]

Click the *Push Down Action* button.  After clicking it, the result will look something like this:

[image: NLA action screenshot]

Double-click "NlaTrack" and rename it to the name of the animation that you would like to see in the exported glTF file.  If multiple objects are to move as part of a single animation, copy-and-paste this name exactly to all of the NLA tracks that participate in the animation.

After exporting to glTF, all NLA tracks with exactly the same name will be rolled into a single glTF animation of that name.  NLA tracks with different names will be different animations within the file.

Some time ago I made a [YouTube video demoing this process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNA8ujgtogM).