# Multiple animations on one mesh, gltf export

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, gltf, nla-editor

the object I'm working on consists of several meshes. all of those meshes are connected to one animation (let's call it "open"), and one of the meshes is connected to another animation ("headrest").

my goal is to create two independent animations for one object (one button would trigger "open" for all meshes, another button would trigger "headrest" for the mesh connected to it).

before the final export, only "headrest" animation is selected in NLA editor (toggle channel muting). that way "headrest" works like it should be working, but the "open" is merged with "headrest". I want to separate those.

gltf file: https://easyupload.io/0w1qag

you can compile it here: https://threejs.org/editor/

"headrest" animation works fine. speaking of "open" animation, I deleted all keyframes connected to the bone that moves the headrest, but somehow it uses the keyframes from "headrest" animation (I need it to be fixed).

thanks in advance!

Comment: For multiple Blender animations exporting to glTF, check out my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267223/18161

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in two ways: either exporting without compression, or updating to Blender 3.3 where they fixed some issues with glTF.