# mutli object animated gltf for working, same Nla track name

Tags: gltf, nla-editor

I am making a PEB animation showing it being assembled. when I export a single object, it works fine but with all objects selected it still shows animation for one object with the animation bar moving for the whole animation. how can I fix that? Please.

[image]

Comment: I wrote about merging animations here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267223/18161

Comment: hi, all the NLA stips have the same name NlaTrack, there are about 500 objects in the scene and all have different animations.  for context, I used animation nodes to make the animation and baked it using the option bake option of animation nodes. all the frames for each object start from 1 to the end frame of 1500. do you think that could be a problem?

Comment: found the solution, I renamed all NLA tracks one by one again and it works now. would have been great if there was a workaround for renaming all NLA tracks simultaneously.