# Blender to GLB: how do I setup NLA for multiple animations?

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have model with animated armature that follows a path but when I export to GLB only the armature is animated. I understand this is something to do with NLA tracks but I can't figure out how to rename/push down. Would be super grateful for your tips?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sLttm6d7cSR6gRhtEogxhNonzGGRPVKO?usp=sharing

Comment: There's a comprehensive video introduction to the NLA editor by CGDive [here](https://youtu.be/tAo7HxxxA08).

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267223/18161

Comment: thanks - I think my issue is slightly different as one of the animations is a follow path, and for some reason it doesn't show up in action editor so I can't use push down.

Comment: Please use blend exchange to share you blender file, https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: THX everyone @JohnEason et al
I fixed it 

My armature was parented to an object that followed path constraint.
I baked the object, and the armature and was then able to use PUSH DOWN in NLA editor. 
I renamed the NLA tracks so they had the same name (as they need to run simultaneously in GLB) 
I had to delete all other actions from Blender File as this was messing up GLB animations.