How to manually merge active actions for GLTF export?
Currently working on a project that involves animating a truck bed camper unfolding, which has to be exported to GLTF with a couple different animations.
The animation is created in Blender using empties parented to each other, with pistons created using Damped Track constraints on empties.
All the animated empties have NLA tracks created for them.
Exporting as GLTF works great, as long as I enable "Bake All Objects" and "Active Actions Merged".
The issue is, I don't want all the active actions merged - there need to be a couple different actions that can play separately. But if I disable "Active Actions Merged", all the animated objects export as separate actions, which also isn't what I want.
Is there any way to selectively merge actions together, without simply merging all of them?

Does this answer your question?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267223/18161

Thanks - actually no because I just figured out a similar solution on my own haha, but I appreciate the comment. Will post my solution below.

Figured out a solution.

Use "NLA tracks for "animation mode" in export settings (instead of "Merge All Actions")
By default this ignores empties that have constraints but no keyframes
To solve this problem, add keyframes to any empties that need to be animated (they don't need to create any motion, just add a basic keyframe at the beginning and end of the frame range)
This will create an NLA track for the empty - this can then be "pushed down" to create an NLA channel, which can be renamed to be part of a certain action.

