export glTF 2.0 with multiple animations
I am trying to get it to export multiple animations of multiple items.I am trying to get it into twinmotion

The animations look perfect in Blender. I have put the items into NLA and baked them. The export settings should work, I feel like I am missing something...
When I bring it into twinmotion only one animation comes in. I should be able to get them all in.
I have tried exporting to fbx and gltf 2.0.

Did you click "Push Action Down"?  See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267223/18161


Push your actions down in the Nonlinear Animation editor by clicking on the push down icon at the right edge.

Name the tracks with the name you want them to have in the glTF. If you want multiple object animations to be part of the same track, name them all the same.

In the glTF exporter, check "Animations", and use the default setting of Animation Mode: Actions


My suggestion: for real-time usage I usually want to disable the Sampling Animations option. When this is enabled, the exporter will create a unique keyframe for every channel for every animation track for every frame of animation; this can help with differences between rotation interpolation between some Blender settings and the glTF runtime, but it generally bloats the glTF and slows down real-time animation track computation.



